# creating css sprites with images called by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, sprite

I tested my website on page speed on google page speed and I got the suggestion that combine images into css sprite and gave a list of images.

I read every link/article available regarding it and many of them shows example also.

I have used jquery and images are called in that there is no html call for the class in which images are included.

Here is the sample css code for one image:

```
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a { display:block; width:22px; height:22px; background:url(../images/bullets.png) no-repeat; }
```

nivo-controlNav class is not called anywhere in html code it is called implicitly by jquery.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

I have got the css sprite image and css code for the image but cannot judge where and how to call it from html code.

I am a newbie to css.
Every suggestion is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: It is by default used by nivo slider.

Comment: Nivo slider is cool but abit complicated what about doing js cycle its super easy.. and then you just do like with normal images when you make sprites of controls

Comment: @Khushbu-See this link http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ which gives us info how to use it

Comment: I see no code in your question.  jQuery or otherwise

Answer (score 1):

i think if you give background-position each image class, this problem will solve.

```
.image-1{background-position:x y;}
```

[check this page more info about background position.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)